# Editing Others' Posts

Tags: feature-request

I see lots of cases were questions, and even answers are being edited by folks other than those who originally posted the question/answer. Often the edits are minor corrections to spelling or capitalization. But sometimes the edits change the content of the original post is a significant way.

I always assumed that the poster would be informed and approve of any changes others make to their posts. But I have found that is not true.

Could we have a policy imposed where posters must always approve changes to their posts (except where a post was removed for abusing a policy) before such changes are applied? The poster should be given the option of approving, rejecting, or editing any changes applied by others.

Comment: In addition to what has been pointed out by Kevin Reid, please also consider [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/editing) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding [the specific case you might be thinking of](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/1890/revisions), now that you point it out I see that my edit did remove a distinction you were making, and I'm sorry for that; thank you for noticing and fixing it.

If an edit does make a substantial change to the meaning of an answer, the edit should be rejected (if being reviewed) with the **radical change** reason, or fixed if already made. Additionally, as the author of a post, you can make binding decisions to approve or reject *suggested* edits to your own posts, and you will be notified of such edits in your Stack Exchange inbox. However, those who have gained [the privilege to edit posts, or review suggested edits,](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) are expected to be able to use that privilege wisely.

If you want your words to forever stay exactly as you wrote them, you're unlikely to find satisfaction; community editing to make even good content better is generally seen as one of the best features of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Actually I have not yet come across a specific case that I would call significant. But it is bound to happen, and at the rate that I see content being edited on this forum, I think it's bound to have already happened - and thus my suggestion. Posters shouldn't have to keep coming back to see if their posts have mutated. Editing others' work should be done judiciously and only when necessary, and all such edits should at least generate a notification that gets delivered to the original author.

Comment: @user2338215 There is already [a notification for when one of your posts is edited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/notify-us-when-one-of-our-posts-is-edited). (I just checked and I got one recently, so that feature's still there.) if you didn't get one, that would be a bug to report.

Comment: Looking through my "Recent inbox messages" I see that I did receive a notification of the edit. It probably arrived before I even realized I had an inbox - I'm a noob. I think the inbox notification is probably adequate - provided that it happens for every edit to any question or answer regardless who does the edit. Is there a written policy regarding under what circumstances edits should be made by "the privilege to edit posts, or review suggested edits" folks?

Comment: I think I found it: http://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit